# Solving a puzzle related to Mars Attacks

Tags: cipher

I need help for solving this puzzle.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: context might help here.

Comment: yeah trying that

Comment: I mean I noted the phrase "next question", so there is previous question(-s) and the puzzle can be unsolvable for us, since we don't know what are previous tasks and things like this.

Comment: its nothing like that

Comment: previous question is irrelevant to this

Comment: Ack ack ack ack ack!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is either

> "See you again" or "Young, Wild and Free" by Wiz Khalifa

Writing out the letters of the alphabet underneath the letters as they appear on a keyboard gives a method of encrypting/decrypting information.

QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Under these rules, using for decryption, we have that

> V $\rightarrow$ W, O $\rightarrow$ I, M $\rightarrow$ Z, A $\rightarrow$ K, I $\rightarrow$ H, Q $\rightarrow$ A, S $\rightarrow$ L, Y $\rightarrow$ F.

Hence the message from the Good Samaritan becomes

> WIZ KHALIFA

Looking at his discography, I reckon the song is either

> "See you again" referring to seeing the martians on their return visit to Earth

or

> "Young, Wild and Free" which was a song Wiz recorded with Snoop Dogg but also featured Bruno MARS.

Comment: Awesome Dude!The answer is "See You Again"